# combobox with changing directory in c#

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm working on a bit of c# code that first has the user click a directory button and select a folder. How do I load a combobox with the contents of that folder(it will be text files)? Since the dir can change depending on the folder selected, I'm not sure how to go about this.

From comment:

```
foreach (String file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(?????)) {
  comboBox1.Items.Add(new System.IO.FileInfo(file).Name);
}
```

I don't know what to put in place of ???? to get it to work.

Comment: foreach (String file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(?????))
   {

    comboBox1.Items.Add(new System.IO.FileInfo(file).Name); 
   }                                                                  I don't know what to put in place of ???? to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something as simple as this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  using (FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog()) {
    if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
      UpdateComboBox(fbd.SelectedPath);
    }
  }
}

private void UpdateComboBox(string folderPath) {
  comboBox1.Items.Clear();
  foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(folderPath)) {
    comboBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(fileName));
  }
}
```

Assumes WinForms.

Comment: Thanks so much! This makes a lot of sense. The only problem I'm having is it's throwing an error of the DialogResult.OK saying "System.Nullable<bool> does not contain a definition for 'OK'".

Comment: @user1162643 The posted code certainly won't produce that error.  Did you make your own `DialogResult` variable that is `Nullable<bool>`?  Otherwise, `DialogResult` is a simple built-in enum.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to get the result of the directory selection.

Then you would use GetFiles:

```
   var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt")
```

That would return an array of textfiles.

Then you could loop through that:

```
foreach(var file in files)
{
   combobox.Item.Add(file);
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't `GetFiles()` return an array of strings?  I don't think there is a `filename` property for that.

Comment: yeah sorry was doing it off the top of my head not in front of VS.